Request had insufficient authentication scopes in Google Calendar API
I'm trying to create a new secondary calendar on a user's account using the scope /auth/calendar.app.created, which is supposed to Make secondary Google calendars, and see, create, change, and delete events on them.  Here is the relevant code:
def authenticate_implicit_with_adc(project_id = 'tb-read'):
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
    buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

@app.route('/users/<user_id>/oauth')
def connect_to_google(user_id):

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret_962453248563-u7b22jm1ekb7hellta4vcp05t24firg4.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created')
    flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/createcalendar'
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type="offline", include_granted_scopes="true", prompt="consent")

    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/createcalendar')
def create_calendar():
    """Create a new google calendar for the user"""

    if not g.user: 
        flash ('Please log in', 'danger')
        return redirect('/') 
    
    calendar = {
        'summary': 'TB Read Calendar'
    }
    created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()
    user = db.session.execute(db.select(User).where(User.user_id == g.user.user_id)).scalar()
    user.calendar_id = created_calendar['id']
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    print('****************************')
    print(user.calendar_id)
    service.close()

    return redirect(f'/users/{g.user.user_id}/calendar')

The oauth seems to be proceeding ok, but when I get to creating the new calendar I get googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]"> which says I have insufficient scopes.
I've tried adding a broader scope, which didn't help, which leads me to think I'm doing something wrong in the oauth so the api client isn't getting the scopes at all, but I'm very much a beginner and not sure I truly understand how Google authorization works. I've tried several variations I found in the google docs for setting up the connection to google and none of them worked.
